# PHP print into css style box

Tags: php, css

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style type="text/css">

.yellow-box { position:absolute; top:100px; left:500px; width:300px; height:300px; background:yellow 
} 

</style>

<div class = "yellow-box" > 
</div>

<body>

<h1> TEST  </h1>

<?php

for ($i=1; $i < 11; $i++) {

  print ($i) ;

  print ("<br>") ;

  }

?>

</body>

</html>
```

Sorry if this is really simple and basic but what do I have to add to make the numbers 1 to 10 appear in the yellow box ? (This a simplified version of what I am wanting to achieve)

Answer (score 1):

Your style needs to be in your head. And put your PHP code inside the div and put the div inside the body.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Yellow box experiment</title>
    <style>
      .yellow-box {
          position:absolute; top:100px; left:500px; width:300px; 
          height:300px;background:yellow
      }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="yellow-box">
    <?php
       for ($i=1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
         echo $i . "<br>";
       }
   ?>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this - moving the php code INSIDE your DIV tags.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style type="text/css">

.yellow-box { position:absolute; top:100px; left:500px; width:300px; height:300px; background:yellow 
} 

</style>

<div class = "yellow-box" > 
</div>

<body>

<h1>

<?php 

for ($i=1; $i < 11; $i++) {

  print ($i) ;

  print ("<br>") ;

  }
?>

</h1>

</body>

</html>
```